# What are the silent changes of behaviour when updating c++?

Tags: c++, c++14, upgrade

Consider a C++98 code base that I would like to update to C++14.

I really want to do this upgrade as it would benefit the code base gratelly, the question is the burden of such update.

The problem is that this code base does not have a comprehensive test suite. Therefore after updating, some changes of behaviour that would not get caught in compile time, might go unnoticed.

Now, I know the standards comittee rarely introduces breaking changes, especially silent ones, and yet some changes are inevitable.

For risk analysis and timeline purposes of upgrading the language version I need to know the following:

1. Is there a comprehensive (or partial) list of such changes?
2. Is there an automated tool that can point to potential instances of silent breakages in my code base (to be fixed manually)?

Comment: The C++ standard appendix C is quite comprehensive.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ standard itself has such a list. I believe it isn't entirely comprehensive (especially if you do things that often work in practice but aren't allowed by the standard, like [extending the `std` namespace in unsupported ways](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std).

If you look at [Appendix C of the C++14 standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/#diff), you see that it lists differences between C++17 and older versions of C++ going back to C++03. Section C.1 is irrelevant for your purposes because it's a comparison with C, but [C.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/diff.cpp03) and [C.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/diff.cpp11) is probably helpful.

If you want to convert to another standard instead (C++17 is currently the most recent published version and I'd highly recommend migrating to that if you're migrating anyway), you can find links to those in browsable HTML form [here](https://github.com/timsong-cpp/cppwp). Note that none of these are the *official* standard, but they are very close; the only differences are minor editorial fixes in one direction or the other.

I am not aware of any automated tools to help with the migration, but I wouldn't be surprised if any existed.

Comment: This list is indeed very large, however it is broad and not very practical. It touches everything in points: to quote "code that relies on this behaviour might change it's meaning" - to understand exactly what the change can be requires "diffing" the relevent parts of the standards, which most people (including myself) can't really do.

Comment: @Omer - "Diffing" the standard documents is complicated by the C++14 document being 600 pages larger than C++98.  :-)

Comment: @BoPersson Well obviously no :) I meant for every entry in appendix C that says "code that relies on this behaviour might change it's meaning" to look on this "behaviour" in the standard and see exactly what the change is.

Comment: @OmerRosler The changes are summarized in those points and usually tnere’s some sort of elaboration. For example, it says “Valid C++ 2003 code that uses these functions may fail to compile with this International Standard.” right below a list of precisely which functions changed. I agree it’s not ideal but it does still seem useful.

Comment: Indeed, it is useful to point the general direction. How about the tooling? Does some modernization tool take into account the _unwanted_ changes of behaviour?